# Copy the current URL into a new alert window using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I struggled for hours to find out how to make a javascript function to copy the current URL into a new alert window.
For example, when a user click "Share this page", then a new alert window appears with the URL selected in an input text box:

[image]

How can I make it done with javascript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As simple as this:

```js
prompt('Please copy the following URL:', window.location);
```

Comment: Really thanks a lot. It's so simple and it worked like a magic.

Comment: @Peter You are welcome. And the good thing, you don't need to use any external libraries and care about browser support: this functionality was there back to 90s.

Answer (score 1):

```
prompt('Please copy the following URL', window.location.href)
```

Answer (score 1):

For a better user experience you may consider allowing access to the clipboard with [clipboard.js](http://zenorocha.github.io/clipboard.js/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simple snippet code, `window.location` as the second param in `prompt`.

```js
window.copyURL = function(){
prompt("Press [Ctrl + c] to copy the url :",window.location);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="copyURL()">Copy URL </button>
```